# Why is one <div> overlapping another <div>?

Tags: html, css

Here is my page's HTML:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="conteudo_representantes"></div>
  <div class="rodape"></div>
</body>
```

I have content inside the `.conteudo_representantes` *div* that is going over the `.rodape` (footer) *div*.

Here is my page's CSS:

```
.conteudo_representantes {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    min-height:586px;
    margin-top:40px;
    position: relative;
}


.rodape {
    position: relative;
    width:960px;
    height:50px;
    margin:36px auto;
    background:transparent url(../img/header_pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
```

The full page source can be found in this [example](http://www.alsite.com.br/novo/abruzzo/representantes.html).  (Click on the second line of the list where it says: **02 - São Paulo - Capital**, to see this problem in action.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that your div **conteudo_representantes** is not wrapping all of its contents properly, so the footer is in the correct relative position as far as it is concerned and the **representantes** div is overflowing for some reason

EDIT:

It is actually to do with the way you have managed your `float` attributes.

Your div **representantes** floats left, but the footer does not. You can test this by turning `float:left` off from the **representantes** div.

This is a common cause of divs overlapping.

When laying out a HTML page, consider how each div element stacks onto the next. The `float` element will ultimately decide how the divs stack

Heres a quick [guide](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html) to stacking elements correctly

Comment: yes, it is.. i think i need some div before the #conteudo_representantes and #rodape to wrap them, right?

Comment: Try floating 'rodape' left and wrapping it inside the main div. I notice you dont have a main wrapper div to center all of your content, it is a good idea to try this out now

Comment: wow i see some progress now.. if i set 'float:left' on the footer, this works right, this stop the hovering, but my footer is dont on center of the page.... i have updadet the page on the link i provide on question.. see this again...

Comment: @AndrewPeacock that actually sorts the problem out. Cheers Andrew.

Comment: but i cant center the footer now... i use: `margin: 36px; auto.` and this dont work..

Comment: Remove `float:left` and add `clear:both` is what Andrew means

Comment: yes.. i do that... but if i set `clear:both` i loose the **margin top** of **footer**

Comment: i'm done... i set `margin-botton:36px` on div **representantes** and works fine!... thanks @AndrewPeacock and @JackalopeZero for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, it's because you have `min-height` specified for `#container`. This allows it to grow should the content exceed that height. And because it's `min-height`, it's not pushing the footer down when the content grows larger.

**Update:** Problem should be solved by adding a `clear:both` property to the `#footer`.

Comment: What happens if you apply `display:block;` to either or both?